# FluentValidation how to return message in several languages

Tags: c#, .net, api, fluentvalidation

I have this class :

```cs
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to validate the `FirstName` property. I have to return a message in several languages 'FR', 'EN' like this :

```cs
{
    "FR": "Erreur",
    "EN": "Error"
}
```

with this validator :

```cs
public class CustomerValidator : AbstractValidator<Customer>
{
    public CustomerValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.FirstName)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage("Error");
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Another option could be to return the message depending on the `Language` property.

Comment: Take a look at [Fluent validation - Localization page](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/localization.html), this might help you

Comment: I read that but that's not request to what I want.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a resource file and define the localized strings in it. and based on the language you can get the message in that language.

you can create the resource file by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/create-resource-files) link.

Also, refer to [this](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/localization.html) for fluent validation localization.

Comment: Ok but the ressource value to return is based on the Language of the Customer without that how the API  know what test to return. The localization has to be based on this property.

Comment: @Kris-I you want to do this only for one error message or multiple?

Comment: @viveknuage It's an API the customer can be english or french speaker then I want the validation message send back to the customer in french or english depending the Language property.

Comment: @Kris-I  I mean you want to handle only for one string right?

Comment: @viveknuage All the strings coming from the validations

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll create a resource file for each language you`ll support. You can refer to [Microsoft documentation on how to create and work with .resx files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/work-with-resx-files-programmatically).

Then, change your FluentValidator Rule to use your resource file instead of a static string:

```
RuleFor(x => x.FirstName)
            .NotEmpty()
            .WithMessage(m => MyResouceFile.Error); // Notice the resource file reference
```

FluentValidator will automatically pick the language based on the Current Culture.

Your consumers will have to specify which language they want it back. There are different options, for example it can be specified in the url: `www.example.com/fr/controller/endpoint`. Or they can use the HTTP header `Accept-Language`. Which one to pick is a design decision you'll have to make.

If you opt for the `Accept-Language` path, you can set the current culture, preferably in a pipeline, like following:

```
if(Request.UserLanguages != null && Request.UserLanguages.Count > 0)
{
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(Request.UserLanguages[0], false);
}
else
{
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; // optionally you may use a sensible default to you, like en-US
}
```